# How to push-back a vector in elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

I found some instructions to pushback with a vector using a function called [`vector-push`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_vec_ps.htm), the problem is that I think it only works with common lisp.

What if I want to push to the back of a vector in elisp? How can I do that?

I'm familiar with C++ where you say something like [`vector.push_back(element);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

The documentation on vector functions in elisp is quite sparse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Emacs Lisp does not have extensible vectors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequences-Arrays-Vectors.html).

You can emulate them, of course, just like you can emulate [multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42603751/850781), reinventing the wheel in this day and age is a waste of time.

Why use an inadequate tool?

Comment: Just for future reference then, if I want to use a resizable array in elisp, how might I go about it?

Comment: you don't. you either avoid them (if you are stuck with elisp) or you use a better tool. do NOT reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Then what's the difference between an array and a vector in elisp? I know that vector's are a subset of arrays, but is there something a vector can do that an array cant, or vice-versa?

Comment: [rtfm](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequences-Arrays-Vectors.html)

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Vector-Functions.html

Function: vconcat &rest sequences

This function returns a new vector containing all the elements of sequences. The arguments sequences may be proper lists, vectors, strings or bool-vectors. If no sequences are given, the empty vector is returned.

The value is either the empty vector, or is a newly constructed nonempty vector that is not eq to any existing vector.

try this:

```
(vconcat '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
;; returns [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```